# Finding sign changes using filter and 2-D convolution

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter

Let `S` be the matrix holding the sign of a data matrix `D` that is `S=sign(D)`. I want to find vertical changes between two following cells in `S`. (I am trying to detect edges after a difference of Gaussian). To avoid noise I want to preform this only if I find an edge in two consequence pixels.

I have implemented this code which is mathematically good (answered my requirements). (applies some weight to the edges)

```
        [D,S]=DogCalc(FileName);%the function is in the end of this file

        edges=zeros(size(D));
        for i=1:rowSize*columnSize-columnSize
            if(S(i)~=S(i+1)&&S(i+columnSize)~=S(i+1+columnSize))%apply weighted edge for horizontal edge 
               edges(i)=abs((D(i)*S(i+1)-D(i+1)*S(i))/(S(i+1)-S(i)));
            elseif(S(i)~=S(i+columnSize)&&S(i+1)~=S(i+1+columnSize))%apply weighted edge for vertical edge
               edges(i)=abs((D(i)*S(i+columnSize)-D(i+columnSize)*S(i))/(S(i+columnSize)-S(i)));
            end
        end
        imshow(edges);
```

I tried to using a filer to avoid the for loop to no avail. The filter was suppose to extract a matrix with `1` in the interesting pixels which answers the conditions (replace the `if` statements). everything goes wrong:

```
        Tester=[1 -1; 1 -1];
        %V for vertical and H for horizontal
        VEdges=abs(imfilter(S,0.25*Tester,'same'));
        HEdges=abs(imfilter(S,0.25*Tester.','same'));
        VEdges(VEdges<1)=0;
        HEdges(HEdges<1)=0;
```

- Is it doable\correct using a filter?
- If so how and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, this worked for me (in finding changes in sign where in two adjacent locations in the matrix). I assume that S contains values either 0 or 1:

```
abs(imfilter(S, [1 -1; 1 -1]/4, 'replicate'))>0.5-eps
```

explanation: your filter shape is correct, but I'm not sure what you are looking for. An exact match (an edge in two adjacent locations) will give you a value of about 0.5 or -0.5, but only "numerically" (because of fft used in the application of the filter), so you need to look for something that is close to 0.5 (up to epsilon).

replicate will cause the edges next to the side of the image to be replicated, but you might want to expeirment with the other options of that function.

Comment: I am looking for the same result as the for loop. `S` is either `1` or `-1` (see my edit). The output I am getting is either `0` or `1` the problem is I am getting a doubling of the edge.

Comment: So you want only one '1' where there is a contiguous edge? Run another filter either [1 1] or [1 1]' and threshold the result...

Comment: Yes, I want one `1`. Can you kindly expand on why this filter will help?

Comment: Just the way filters work. a filter will always have the strongest output for something that looks like the filter itself. If you want to look up the deeper math, look for Cauchy-Schwarz inequality [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)